# How does one test optional features in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, conditional-compilation

I have a package I want to add an optional feature to. I've added an appropriate section to my Cargo.toml:

```
[features]
foo = []
```

I wrote an experimental test for the basic functionality of the `cfg!` macro:

```
#[test]
fn testing_with_foo() {
    assert!(cfg!(foo));
}
```

It looks as though I can activate features during testing via either of the options `--features` or `--all-features`:

```
(master *=) $ cargo help test
cargo-test 
Execute all unit and integration tests and build examples of a local package

USAGE:
    cargo test [OPTIONS] [TESTNAME] [-- <args>...]

OPTIONS:
    -q, --quiet                      Display one character per test instead of one line
        ...
        --features <FEATURES>...     Space-separated list of features to activate
        --all-features               Activate all available features
```

Neither `cargo test --features foo testing_with_foo` nor `cargo test --all-features testing_with_foo` works, though.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `cargo test -- --features foo testing_with_foo` (note the `--`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is what @Jmb proposed: `assert!(cfg!(feature = "foo"));`. What it says in the Cargo Book

> This can be tested in code via `#[cfg(feature = "foo")]`.

allows one to confirm that conditional compilation works but doesn't provide a boolean value one can test against. If you want to branch based on the feature at runtime, you need `cfg!`.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is incorrect. Quoting [the Cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html):

> This can be tested in code via `#[cfg(feature = "foo")]`.

Comment: Or to be closer to what the OP wants: `assert!(cfg!(feature = "foo"));`

Comment: Where exactly does it say this in the cargo book? I can't find it anywhere. 'This can be tested in code via #[cfg(feature = "foo")]'

Comment: Link is a little outdated, you can check this - https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html.